# Filter list of strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python code that performs this:

1. Reads the file
2. Converts to a dictionary
3. Filter some parameters in of the dictionary

So this is the type of the dictionary:

```
{'ID1':['100,Cat','100,Cat1','100,Cat2','100,Cat3','99.4,Dog','99.4,Dog1','99.4,Dog3','100,Cat5','100,Cat6']}
```

And now I have to filter the values of the dictionary:

> 1-Filter according to the %: so I fix the first value of the % which in this case is 100 with a margin of 0.05. According to this, I would get

```
['100,Cat','100,Cat1','100,Cat2','100,Cat3']
```

So I did this code:

```
for keys_ID in dictionary.keys():
    list_2 = []
    list_ID = []
    treshold = dictionary[keys_ID][0].split(',')[0]
    for thre in dictionary[keys_ID]:
        thre_split_ID = thre.split(',')[0]
        thre_split_species = thre.split(',')[1].rstrip('\n')
        if float(thre_split_ID) >= float(treshold) - 0.05 and float(thre_split_ID) <= float(treshold) + 0.05:
            if thre_split_species not in list_2:
                list_2 .append(thre_split_species )
                list_ID.append(thre_split_ID)
```

However, this code is giving me this output:

```
['100,Cat','100,Cat1','100,Cat2','100,Cat3','100,Cat5','100,Cat6']
```

in this case the code returned the values that have the same %.

This is the desired output: ['100,Cat','100,Cat1','100,Cat2','100,Cat3']

Can anyone tell me the way to get only the first same results?Thanks

Comment: Do you generate the dictionary? If so, you may prefer not to store a list of strings, but a list of two-tuples, with the first element being your percentage and the second being the label, e.g. Cat.

Comment: Why do you want `'100,Cat1'` but not `'100,Cat5'`? Do you only want the values up to the first that is < 99.5?

Comment: @dspencer or even better, instead of `'100,Cat'` or `[100, 'Cat']`, using `{'Cat': 100}`

Comment: Why do you compute `thre_split_2` if you never use it?  And you use `thre_split_species` but never define it, which should be causing a runtime error.

Comment: It is not clear how you want to filter the strings.

Comment: dictionaries are unordered so the 'first' result is meaningless.  It could change

Comment: @Vorsprung as of CPy3.6 and Py3.7 the dict keeps the order of insertion.

Comment: Can you show us contents of `dictionary` inside the code?

Comment: @ScottHunter I just edited the question to remove that variable, because I print it to see that paramenter

Comment: @tobias_k I want only the first results that are equal.

Comment: @Sofia what do you mean by "first" results?

Comment: @norok2 I want the first results that are equal, but when the result is different I want the list to stop.

Comment: `thre_split_species` is not defined in the posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand the question, you are looking for the values that are within 0.5 of the first value, until you hit a value that is different. For this, you might just add an `else: break` to your `if` condition checking the threshold to stop the loop,

Alternatively, you could use e.g. `itertools.takewhile`:

```
from itertools import takewhile

val = lambda x: float(x.split(",")[0])
dictionary = {'ID1':['100,Cat','100,Cat1','100,Cat2','100,Cat3','99.4,Dog','99.4,Dog1','99.4,Dog3','100,Cat5','100,Cat6']}
for ID in dictionary.keys():
    first, *rest = dictionary[ID]
    filtered = [first, *takewhile(lambda x: abs(val(first) - val(x)) < 0.5, rest)]
    print(filtered)
```

Output:

```
['100,Cat', '100,Cat1', '100,Cat2', '100,Cat3']
```

Comment: What about rewriting: `val = lambda x: float(x.split(",")[0])` as `def val(x): return float(x.split(",")[0])` as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)?

Comment: thank you so much @tobias, this really helped me!